# GulpUglifyError: anytime I make changes to JS

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

I know this topic is widely been talked about on here but I cant seem to get it fixed on my end.

My gulp in VS is not working for some reason so I run gulp outside in a terminal window. When I open a fresh branch and run `gulp all`, it works fine. I then start `gulp watch` which starts fine. Then I go and make the changes to the Javascript I am trying to fix and after I make the change to say JS function and press save, my `gulp watch` blows up and says `"GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript"`.

It seems like everything works until I make a change to the actual JS. I am very new to JS so forgive me if this is a noob question but in my mind, I should be able to make a change, then save it in VS and have gulp watch roll along and re-uglify the JS?

Is it the arrow function in my JS that is causing this error es5 vs es6? Is uglify unable to handle this:

`setTimeout(() => { $("#from_date").data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date); }, 0);`

If so, how can I rewrite this function to work with my uglify()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was getting an uglify error because I was trying to uglify an arrow function => which is an es6 feature. Instead I rewrote the function in es5 syntax to get rid of the =>.